# Asp.net client side cryptography

Tags: cryptography, client-side

How can I sign data with standard .net crypto providers on client side?

Comment: To sign on the client side, you'll need the private key on the client, won't it make your security weak ?

Comment: @TBC - Well no; the private key should be private to the client shouldn't it, not to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on the client side it probably won't be ASP.NET, you'll be using JavaScript (unless you maybe do it in Silverlight).

So that's your answer; use Silverlight if you wish to use ASP.NET, or use JavaScript otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I cann't use Silverlight. Can I reach .net cryptography classes in javascript?

Comment: Not without Silverlight no. I mean, unless you distribute some local executable.